# Floating divs with content directly below selected div, even if divs wrap

Tags: html, css

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

I am trying to create a row of fixed height/width div's with borders (squares):

```
[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] [ 5 ]
```

When one of those div's is clicked, another div, with content relating to the clicked div will appear below:

```
[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] [ 5 ]
--^----------------------------------------
CONTENT #1
-------------------------------------------
```

or

```
[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] [ 5 ]
--------^-----------------------------------
CONTENT #2
--------------------------------------------
```

I have all that working just fine, however I want to improve my code so that if viewing the page from a device with a smaller resolution, and the divs 1-5 wrap, the div with the corresponding content will sit just below the appropriate div:

```
[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] 
--------^-----------------------------------
CONTENT #2
--------------------------------------------
[ 4 ] [ 5 ]
```

Instead of...

```
[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ]
        ^
[ 4 ] [ 5 ]
-------------------------------------------
CONTENT #2
--------------------------------------------
```

I'm searching for a solution that doesn't require clunky javascript's to predetermine screen resolutions etc.

I've been at this for a while Anyone have any thoughts or ideas for me?

Best Regards

Matt

Comment: have you heard about responsive web design ?  you probably looking for a responsive web design.

Comment: I havent until now.  That looks like it encompasses what I need here.  I will read into it further to took for a solution.  Thanks

Comment: then vote up my comment. :P

Comment: I see no way to vote up a specific comment, only an answer.  Do you have any direct examples/code of responsive Web design that would apply to my case?

Comment: that's why you don't know about responsive design. if a design is responsive, you don't have to write any extra codes for that, it'll behave like your requirement in the question.(but you have to design)  and you can't simply ask a question, get codes here. have you tried anything ? please provide some codes that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it with css border-bottom property, so that wherever div's gets positioned there will be a border placed at their bottom.  By using this logic, you can implement the way you mentioned by manipulating div width's with respect to browser width and making adjustments in css properties. I hoped you got an idea to initiate it.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When you talk about the bottom border property are you refering to the pointer which points to the selected div?  If so, I do have that part worked out, I just cant figure out how to get the "content" div to appear directly below the selected div, rather than below all of the divs

Comment: Use an image as your pointer that is referring to selected div. And on selecting a div add pointer image to it. So that this will works as you mentioned in all scenarios and border-bottom will acts as horizantal lines for the divs in each line.

Comment: I have no issue with the pointer.  The issue I have is, if the divs which I have labeled 1 througn 5 wrap due to screen width, the div which holds the content related to div 1 for example, wont appear directly belowthe row which div 1 sits on, it will sit below all the divs

Comment: yes, if all div's aligned in one line then there's no problem with pointer. If they got aligned in more than one line then problem will invoke with pointer. That's why i suggested you to use image as pointer to display it for appropriate selected div. Got it..!!!

Comment: Even if the divs wrap the pointer still works. The divs which I labeled 1-5 in the example are containers that hold a div with a black border, and a pointer image below it.  When the container div is clicked the pointer image is made visible.  But when I make the content div visible, it shows up below div #5 because thats where it is in the source code.  Which is fine if div 1-5 are all on the same line, but if the divs get wrapped, I want the content div directly below the selected div so it matches up to the pointer.

Comment: The pointer is irrelevant and is not causing me any issue.  Its the content div...

Answer (score 0):

Here are content containers that wrap with an additional content container appearing on hover: http://jsbin.com/vepayi/2/edit?html,css,output

Do you need functionality on click? What is the purpose of this UI?

Comment: Thank you for posting that code.  That is close to what I am looking for.  I need that gold div to stretch the length of the screen.   I will play with your code to see if that will work.  I have no issues with js getting on click functionality etc, just with the layout.  The purpose of this page is to show logos of clients that should be inline unless the screen size is so small that the logos wrap or the clients become so numerous that it would just look weird to display them in 1 row.  Once a client logo is clicked a div containing a description will stretch across the screen showing...

Comment: ... Info on the client.  The div showing the info should sit just below the corresponding logo.  This works naturally if all the divs remain inline, but the minute they wrap,  Te div showing the info will show below the last row of client logos, even if the very first client logo was selected.

Answer (score 0):

Id advise not to follow the CSS only route, but just for fun, [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0kLv94w/):

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="num">
        <div class="num_in"><a href="#hell1">1</a>
        </div>
        <div id="hell1" class="hid">hello!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num">
        <div class="num_in"><a href="#hell2">2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="hell2" class="hid">hello 2!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num">
        <div class="num_in"><a href="#hell3">3</a>
        </div>
        <div id="hell3" class="hid">hello3!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num">
        <div class="num_in"><a href="#hell4">4</a>
        </div>
        <div id="hell4" class="hid">hello 4!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num">
        <div class="num_in"><a href="#hell5">5</a>
        </div>
        <div id="hell5" class="hid">hello 5!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #f00;
}
.num {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:10px;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center
}
.hid {
    display:none;
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
.hid:target {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: If he needs click functionality this is the basic approach. However wouldn’t radio buttons make more sense? Both `target` and radio buttons would be pretty egregiously misused here but IMO it doesn’t make sense to pollute the URL for this type of UI.